# Java JTable not showing on my Frame after populating it

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that should get data from the DB, put this data into a DefaultTableModel, then put that model into the JTable and show it. Sounds simple, but i am new to programming and java and i can't seem to find a solution why it's not showing up, just stays blank in the frame. I tried the code below and many other variants.

First off the Scrollpane, JTable, Frame etc (setControl is for showing the frame its controller):

```
public class CustomerWindow extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton btnAllBuCust;
    private Control control;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable tableCustomer;

public CustomerWindow(Control control) {
    setSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    setLocation(new Point(100, 100));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Customer");
    setControl(control);
    setVisible(true);
    getContentPane().add(getPanelTable(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

private JPanel getPanelTable() {
    if (panelTable == null) {
        panelTable = new JPanel();
        panelTable.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        panelTable.add(getScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelTable.add(getTableCustomer(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    return panelTable;
}

    private JTable getTableCustomer() {
    if (tableCustomer == null) {
        tableCustomer = new JTable();
        tableCustomer.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    }
    return tableCustomer;
}

private JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
    if (scrollPane == null) {
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tableCustomer);
        scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);

    }
    return scrollPane;
}
```

The button that should fire of the new JTable:

```
    private JButton getBtnAllBuCust() {
    if (btnAllBuCust == null) {
        btnAllBuCust = new JButton("All Business Customers");
        btnAllBuCust.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel model = control.getModelBuCust();
                tableCustomer = new JTable(model);
            }
        });
        btnAllBuCust.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 25));
    }
    return btnAllBuCust;
}
```

The getModelBuCust() in my controller class:

```
    public DefaultTableModel getModelBuCust() {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    ResultSetMetaData resultMD = null;
    String query;
    int numberOfColumns;
    Object[] rowData;
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();

    try {
        con = Driver.connectionToMySQL();

        query = "SELECT companyname, employeefirstname, employeelastname FROM businesscustomer";

        stm = con.prepareStatement(query);

        result = stm.executeQuery();

        testBuCustResultSet(result);

        resultMD = result.getMetaData();

        numberOfColumns = resultMD.getColumnCount();

        while (result.next()) {
            rowData = new Object[numberOfColumns];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i) {
                rowData[i] = result.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            dtm.addRow(rowData);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Tools.cleanUp(con, stm, result);
    }
    return dtm;
}
```

Rest of the methods:

```
public class Driver {


    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/customer";


    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public static Connection connectionToMySQL() {

        try {

            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            return con;

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }



}

public class Tools {

public static void cleanUp(Connection con, Statement stm, ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stm != null) {
                stm.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // XXX Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The methods cleanUp and connectionToMySQL are taken care of, they work. Just to connect to DB and to clean up con, rs and stm.

When i click the button i also start testBuCustResultSet which justs prints out the data in the ResultSet into the console, and it does show me everything, its all in the ResultSet, but my frame still stays blank.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And where do you add the table to frame?  You realise that you're creating a new instance of `JTable` in your `ActionListener` which will have no relationship with the one created with `getTableCustomer`?  I would be better to use the `JTable` returned by `getTableCustomer` and set it's `TableModel`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Added the necessary data

Comment: use Vector<Object>, I'd be hardcode (start with) rowData(result.getDouble/String/Date/Int) because you ignore data types from metadata, then to override getColumnClass for proper (various) data types, more in Oracle tutorial how to use Tables

Comment: search for Java + ResultSetTableModel or better TableFromDatabase to avoids to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Don't do `tableCustomer = new JTable(model);` in your `ActionListener`, instead do something more like `getTableCustomer().setModel(model)`